# Why when using FragmentContainerView, the design tab is not refreshing?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

While im learning to navigate between fragment, i've got this warning.

```
Replace the <fragment> tag with FragmentContainerView.
```

So i easily fixed the warning by replacing the tag and now the design tab is not showing the fragment that i have make. This is the screenshot of it: [not normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGK86.png)

This is the  screenshot of normal condition when I'm using fragment tab. [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4rEJ.png)

The app is running normally even when using FragmentContainerView. So, anyone can help me why the design tab is not showing when using FragmentContainerView even the code is running normally? I have try restarting the ide but its not working. Tq in advance.

Comment: Is your Android Studio up-to-date? I used to have the same issue, but it got fixed in the latest versions.

Comment: yes, It's in latest version

Comment: This seems odd. If you don't have an error message in Android Studio, you could try a clear caches + restart if you haven't already tried.

Comment: Still the same. I also tried to sync to gradle but it's not working.